# Pass id to every <Link>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, generics, hyperlink

I have problem with passing id to every  depending on id.

I have a list of components (with different props) and need to add interaction to every component, which link to that page depends on id.

```
export const ResultItem = (id) =>

         <div>
            <Link to={{ 
                  pathname: `/idea/${id}`,
                }}><button>View Recipe</button></Link>
          </div>
;
```

Later in child component i need access to this id for  make an API CALL to endpoint, with specific id to get data and render them.

```
class Component extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {

    // how can i declare variable depends on id here (i have id in url too

    axios
    fetch('http://localhost:50647/fund/GetFund/{id}')
    (API CALL LOGIC)
  }

  render(){
      return(
          <div>  
          </div>
      )
  }
};
```

How can I pass id to child component via Link and declare it as variable to make an API CALL depends on id?

Comment: What routing library (React Router, Reach Router, something else) are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id like this inside your page component:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

With your code using `withRouter(component)`

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.fetch('http://localhost:50647/fund/GetFund/{this.props.match.params.id}')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router, you can use:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

To access a path variable (path param).

Be careful that you should use withRouter HOC to have access to routing information in props.

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't work for you, maybe you can try:

```
const linkCustomProps = { id: 4 };
const toObject = { pathname: "/", customProps: linkCustomProps };
<Link to={toObject}>Click me</Link>;
```

Then you can access the value by:

```
this.props.location.customProps.id
```

BTW I'm using client-side HashRouting in my specific situation.

Comment: i can't declare linkCustomProps inside ResultItem component